# Implementing 'curly' and 'access' "chaining" functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, chaining

I read [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/) on the mathworks blog about functional programming in matlab, and two of the helper functions there were:

```
paren = @(x, varargin) x(varargin{:});
curly = @(x, varargin) x{varargin{:}};
```

The obvious third one to complete the trio (and in keeping with the five-letter theme) would be:

```
acces = @(x, field) x.(field);
```

Putting the discussion of whether it's a good idea to implement chaining in this manner or not in matlab aside (note: octave supports chaining by default), `paren` seems to work well, as expected; however, `curly` and `acces` have a major drawback; consider the following code:

```
>> C = {1,2,3,4; 2,3,4,5; 3,4,5,6; 4,5,6,7};
>> A = [curly(C, 3, ':')]
A =
     3
```

i.e. the expected *sequence* generation didn't happen.
(note that this code works as expected in Octave, i.e. `A = [3,4,5,6]` )

Equally, `acces` does not produce a sequence in matlab

```
>> S = [struct('name', 'john'), struct('name', 'jim')];
>> A = {acces(S, 'name')}
A = 
    'john'
```

(whereas Octave produces the expected `A = {'john', 'jim'}` )

I understand that the difference is probably more a matter of implementation in terms of **a.** how functions return stuff in matlab vs octave, and/or **b.** how sequences are generated from cells and structs in the two languages.

However, is there a programmatic way to get matlab to perform the intended operation above?
In other words, is there a way to define `curly` and `acces` functions that return a sequence (extra bonus for anonymous function :p ) like octave does?

---

PS. The answer I'm looking for is not the trivial
*"to get multiple arguments out use varargout"* one.
PS2. <s>I tested this on Matlab 2013b, so I'm not aware if this behaviour has been "fixed" in later versions (though I highly doubt it).</s> Tested on latest matlab online at http://matlab.mathworks.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer: Less of an answer and more of some random musings**

The issue here is that, in MATLAB, a single function (anonymous or otherwise) is incapable of returning a comma-separated list the way that dot referencing and `{}` indexing can.

Even MATLAB's internal functions for performing the referencing are incapable of doing so:

```
subsref(S, substruct('.', 'name'))
%   john

builtin('_dot', S, 'name')              % Only works pre-2015b
%   jim

subsref(C, substruct('{}', {3 ':'}))
%   3

builtin('_brace', C, 3, ':')            % Only works pre-2015b
%   3
```

**But** what a single function *can* do in MATLAB, is return multiple outputs. This is precisely how `subsref` and the other built-ins return the multiple values you're hoping for

```
S = struct('name', {'john', 'jim'});

[val1, val2] = subsref(S, substruct('.', 'name'));
[val1, val2] = builtin('_dot', S, 'name');

C = num2cell(magic(3));

[val1, val2, val3] = subsref(C, substruct('{}', {3, ':'}));
[val1, val2, val3] = builtin('_brace', C, 3, ':');
```

Now this doesn't really help your helper anonymous function since it requires knowledge of how many outputs to expect and that in turn depends on the inputs.

For your `acces` function, it's relatively straight forward to determine the number of outputs so you could easily do something like:

```
[A{1:numel(S)}] = acces(S, 'name');
```

Unfortunately, you can't do that inside of an anonymous function, and there's also  no easy way to get a non-cell array out apart from wrapping this with a follow-up call to `cell2mat`

```
[A{1:numel(S)}] = acces(S, 'name');
A = cell2mat(A);
```

You *could* create some anonymous functions to do these various operations, but they are messy.

```
access_cell = @(s,n)arrayfun(@(x)acces(x,n), s, 'uniform', 0);
access_array = @(s,n)arrayfun(@(x)acces(x,n), s, 'uniform', 1);
```

As for your `curly` you could instead use `paren` to grab a subset of the cell array as a cell and then loop through it with `cellfun` to yield the result.

```
% This is really just using parenthesis
curly_sequence_cell = paren;

curly_sequence_array = @(varargin)cell2mat(paren(varargin{:}));
```

But the *real* solution is just use a temporary variable and then index into that using the typical MATLAB syntax :)

```
S = struct('name', {'john', 'jim'});
A = {S.name};
```

Comment: I didn't know about '_dot' and '_brace', that's cool to know! 
Also thanks for correcting my struct syntax, I hadn't bother to look it up, hahah. Nice workarounds, though I guess, that would make readability even worse than `paren` and `curly` which are questionable enough already ... there's just no way to avoid that bloody temp variable in matlab, is there :p

Comment: still, I do wonder how matlab creates the sequence from a cell / struct under the hood, such that it works when called directly but not when called with `subsref`. I was very surprised when I tried subsref and it didn't work ... until that point I was under the impression that () and {} indexing were just syntactic sugar for subsref ...   (e.g. on octave, subsref, again, works as expected and returns a sequence)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Did a little more exploration with `subsref` and added some info to my answer. While you can coerce `subsref` into giving you all of your values, it's still not easily possible to get a comma separated list out.

Comment: Thanks @Suever ! I suppose this is as close as it'll get on matlab then! Though `[A{:}] = curly(C, 3,':')` is a pretty decent workaround!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou If you just want a cell like that, just use `paren` instead: `A = paren(C, 3, ':')`