# Matlab vector to comma-separated list conversion in one line

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I often want to assign multiple values from a numeric vector to a given field of a structure array.

```
b = 1:3;
x(1).a = b(1);
x(2).a = b(2);
x(3).a = b(3);
```

It seems like there should be a way to make this assignment in a single line but two lines is the best I can come up.

```
c = num2cell(b);
[x.a] = c{:};
```

Is there a way to convert a numeric vector into a comma-separated list? I'm looking for something like:

```
[x.a] = num2csl(b);
```

Note that I am assuming that `length(x) == length(b)` here.

Comment: I like Octave syntax `[x.a] =num2cell(b){:};`

Comment: @rahnema1 I've always wanted that to work in Matlab. I had no idea that it actually worked in Octave. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can just use `struct`. If you provide a cell array as the value for a given fieldname, MATLAB will create a `struct` the same size as that field and use each element within the cell array to populate the corresponding `struct` in the resulting array.

```
x = struct('a', num2cell(b))
```

In general, [there is no way to easily return a comma-separated list from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628157/implementing-curly-and-access-chaining-functions-in-matlab/39628522#39628522)

Comment: My structure `x` frequently has other fields that I don't want to overwrite so I really need a comma-separated list but it sounds like the answer is that there is currently no reasonable way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Often it's also important to remember that there is really no harm in having two lines, especially if they improve readability.

Answer (score 2):

This can only be done with a function if `x` already exists and has the correct number of elements:

```
b = 1:3;

x = repmat(struct, size(b));
[x.a] = num2csl(b);
```

This works if `num2csl.m` makes use of the special output convention `varargout` as follows:

```
function varargout = num2csl(a)
varargout = num2cell(a);
```

If on the other hand, `x` does not already exist, then this one-liner will initialize it, as previously pointed out by Suever:

```
x = struct('a', num2cell(b));
```