# How to directly access functions that return multiple outputs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to directly retrieve the second variable of a function that returns multiple variables. For example, I have the column vector `a` as follows:

```
a = [5 ; 4 ; 3 ; 2 ; 1 ; 9 ; 8 ; 7];
```

And I want to retrieve the index of the minimum value. I know I can do this.

```
[n,i] = min(a);
i
```

But how can I do this essentially in one line? I thought this ould work but it does not:

```
min(a)(1)
```

Comment: What you describe is called 'chaining'. Octave supports this syntax, but matlab does not.  There are weird ways you could get that effect (e.g. specifying a 'paren' function which essentially internally does what you want, as the one described here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39628157/4183191)), but usually they reduce rather than improve readability.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it That question asks to index into the first output variable. This question asks to access the second output variable. These are similar, but different questions.

Comment: However, this question is an identical duplicate of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710466/7328782

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore one of them like this:

```
[n,~] = min(a);
```

Or:

```
[~,i] = min(a);
```

Comment: He is looking for a way to *directly* access the second output without first storing it in a variable

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Also, in this method you didn't store the first variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it might work for you:

```
find( x == min(x), 1, 'first' )
```